# Data manipulation using dcast R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, dcast

I have a data as shown below:

| Data | Flag | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | Yes |
| X | 2 | Yes |
| Y | 1 | Yes |
| Y | 2 | No |
| Z | 1 | Yes |
| Z | 2 | Yes |

and I want to convert it to:

| Data | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | Yes | Yes |
| Y | Yes | No |
| Z | Yes | Yes |

I know I have to use dcast function but I am not able to manipulate the data to the desired form.
Help needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, may you show the output of applying the function `dput` to your data?

Comment: in base R `reshape(dat,  dir = 'wide', timevar = 'Flag', idvar = 'Data')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
reshape2::dcast(dat, Data ~ Flag, value.var = "Answer")
#   Data   1   2
# 1    X Yes Yes
# 2    Y Yes  No
# 3    Z Yes Yes
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Data = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z"), Flag = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Answer = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine. I was unaware of value.var parameter. Thanks again.

Comment: In this case, it works even without that, as `reshape2::dcast(dat, Data ~ Flag)`, since the default value of `value.var` is `guess_value(data)`, a function internal to `reshape2` that tries to find the likely columns. In this case, there is only one column remaining, so it guesses right, but I suggest always being *explicit* about which column you want used as the "value".